# Jquery live edit plugins not working with Zurb Foundation

Tags: jquery, live, zurb-foundation, edit-in-place

I've been trialing several jquery based live edit (edit in place) plugins such as 
[Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and trying to integrate them with Zurb Foundation.

Apparently, Foundation's  foundation.min.js file somehow disables Jeditable and other live edit plugins. They just don't seem to work. You can see more such plugins at http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-live-page-edit-plugins

I can't figure out why Foundation does that. Is there any workaround? Does anyone know of any solution whereby such a plugin has been successfully used with Zurb Foundation

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a few months old but if your using Foundation 4 then you may be having problems if you have zepto initialised instead of jquery. Zepto doesnt seem to be compatible with some jquery functions.